# SQLAlchemy & Complex Queries

Tags: sql, join, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I have to implement ACL for an existing application. 
So I added the a **user**, **group** and **groupmembers** table to the database.
I defined a ManyToMany relationship between **user** and **group** via the association table **groupmembers**. 
In order to protect some ressources of the app (i..e **item**) I added a additional association table **auth_items** which should be used as an association table for the ManyToMany relationship between ***groups/users*** and the specific ***item***.

item has following columns:

- user_id --> user table
- group_id --> group table
- item_id --> item table

at least on of **user_id** and **group_id** columns are set. So it's possible to define access for a group or for a user to a specific item.

I have used the AssociationProxy to define the relationship between users/groups and items.

I now want to display all items which the user has access to and I have a really hard time doing that. Following criteria are used:

- All items which are owned by the user should be shown (item.owner_id = user.id)
- All public items should be shown (item.access = public)
- All items which the user has access to should be shown (auth_item.user_id = user.id)
- All items which the group of the user has access to should be shown.

The first three criteria are quite straightforward, but I have a hard time doing the 4th one.

Here is my approach:

```
clause = and_(item.access == 'public')
if user is not None:
   clause = or_(clause,item.owner == user,item.users.contains(user),item.groups.contains(group for group in user.groups))
```

The third criteria produces an error.

```
item.groups.contains(group for group in user.groups)
```

I am actually not sure if this is a good approach at all.
What is the best approach when filtering manytomany relationships?
How I can filter a manytomany relationship based on another list/relationship?

Btw I am using the latest sqlalchemy (6.0) and elixir version

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contains()` method is for single item check. Assuming your group table is mapped to `Group` class try the following:

```
item.groups.any(Group.id.in_([group.id for group in user.groups])
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  I will try it tomorrow and report back with my findings.